# Question on Definition of a Dual Map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let *L*: *V* --*>* W be a linear map where *V* and *W* are vector spaces over a common field *K*. Why does the definition of the dual map of *L* not require *L* to be onto when the definition involves a composition.

My understanding of the definition follows. Let *W** and *V** be the dual spaces of *V* and *W* respectively. The dual map of *L* is the map *L**: *W** --> *V** given by *L**(*M*) = *ML* for all *M* of *W**. But the composition *ML* exists only if *L* is onto.

If *L* is not onto when written as *L*: *V* --> *W*, then write *L* as *L*:*V* --> *V*(*L*), so *L* is indeed onto. But then there exists vectors of *W* which are excluded from the image *V*(*L*), so *M* cannot map every vector of *W* into *K* and *M* cannot be an element of *W**.

What am I missing? My apologies ahead of time for not using the cool formatting tools.

Comment: why do you think that "the composition ML exists only if L is onto"?  This isn't true.

Comment: For composition ML to exist, the codomain of the map L must be the domain of M. When I read this L must be onto. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Composition_of_Mappings

Comment: @D.Bee Definition 3 in the proofwiki link gives a very explicit picture where the image of the first map is strictly smaller than the domain of the second map.

Comment: WOW! Thanks, it seems I have been too strict with the definition and there are multiple acceptable definitions of a composite map!

Comment: @D.Bee No, I think you are conflating codomain and image.

Comment: True! I see now . . . many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $M \in W^*$, then it is able to map any vector of $W$ to some vector in $W$.

The composition $ML : V \to W$ exists no matter what the image of $L$ is. It does not matter that $M$ doesn't have the opportunity to see vector of $W$ outside the image of $L$; the composition is still a map $V \to W$ since it takes a vector in $V$ and sends it to a vector in $W$.